# Display dynamic table data in 3 columns

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, apache

I want to display mysql table data in 3 columns.I have tried this code. But it doesn't help me. I used var_dump and recieve this output.

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "Gucci" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Business Insider" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Health.com" }
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "Prada" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "Orbitz" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "Time" }
array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "dotTravel" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "Expedia" }
```

> Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Store_Brand\catscheck.php on line 75
>       NULL

I also used echo and recieved this output:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Store_Brand\catscheck.php on line 75
```

**MYSQL**

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sm_brand_name FROM store_manufacture");
$data = Array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    $data[] = $row;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data) / 3; $i++){ // Line 75
    echo '<table><tr>';
    for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++){
        echo  '<td>' . var_dump ($data[ $i + $j * 3])  . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr><tr>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';
?>
```

Comment: It is useful if you show us which is line 75 out of the 16 lines you show us.

Comment: @RiggsFolly updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed your post since I saw it last. But I wrote this based on your original question. It's crude, but at least you can see what's going on...

```
<table>

<?php 
$con    = mysqli_connect(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM yourTable";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$i = 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

    if($i == 0) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . $row[1] . '</td>';
        $i++;
    } elseif ($i == 1) {
        echo '<td>' .$row[1] . '</td>';
        $i++;
    } elseif($i == 2) {
        echo '<td>' . $row[1] . '</td></td>';
        $i = 0;
    }

}
?>

</table>
```

Note, if you're using user-supplied data in your query, you need to use prepared statements, which are a different topic than this one.

Comment: You forgot to close last tr tag which is generating layout issue